# variables transaction in phantomjs, scraping web page

Tags: javascript, loops, web-scraping, phantomjs

I need to scrape url's from one page, I have made this loop using phantomjs. But it isn't working and I don't know why.

```
function() {
var f = fs.open('parse.txt', 'a');
  for (var x = 0; x <= 15; x++) {
    var hrefs = page.evaluate(function(x) {
        return $('.login').eq(x).attr('href');
    }, 'hrefs');
  f.write(hrefs + '\r\n');;
  }
f.close();
```

}

I have tried to do this with an array, but it failed also.

```
var array = [];
page.evaluate(function(array){
  for (var z = 0; z<=15; z++) {
    array.push($('.login').eq(z).attr('href'));
  }
}, array);
console.log(array.length); // 0
```

Comment: On the first code section you are running into a scope issue and you need to remove the "x" from the "function(x)" because the x variable from the for loop is being overridden by the x from the parameter value inside the function method.

Comment: @Kalpers, well, i removed 'x' but it still does'not working. when i use, '3', for example, in first loop **return $('.login').eq(3).attr('href');** i get right result, but when 'x' it does not working..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what worked for me.

```
// var webpage = require('webpage');
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');
var system = require('system');
var address = "https://jquery.org";

console.log("Opening page : " + address);
// var page = webpage.create();
page.open(address, function(status) {
    console.log('Status? '+status);
    if ( status !== 'success') {
      console.log("Failed to load the address...");
      phantom.exit();
    }
    var f = fs.open('parse.txt', 'a');
    for (var x = 0; x<=15; x++ ) {
      var href = page.evaluate(function(x) {
        return $('a').eq(x).attr('href');
      }, x);
      console.log(href);
      f.write(href + '\r\n');
    }
    f.close();
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Some notes.

In the first example, you didn't need to remove "x" from function x, you needed to pass x into page.evaluate as the variable that contained the value to be passed to your function once it was in the browser.

i.e.
`page.evaluate(function(x) {...}, x);`

instead of

`page.evaluate(function(x){...}, hrefs)`

and definitely not

`page.evaluate(function() { return x; })`

given that understanding the appropriate way to accomplish the second example is :

```
var array = page.evaluate(function() {
    var result = [];
    for (var z = 0; z<=15; z++) {
        result.push($('.login').eq(z).attr('href'));
    }
    return result;
});
```

Comment: And I would recommend the array method over the loop method.  The loop method runs page.evaluate 15 times.  It's probably more efficient to run the entire thing in one evaluation if possible, and it is.

Comment: oh, thank you. now i understand how it works) and i moved to Casperjs and found it much easier and flexible than phantom